# r.walk and r.external grass function problems in python console

Tags: python, pyqgis, grass-gis, qgis-processing

I would like to run the r.walk grass function with these codes:

```
import processing
from qgis.core import QgsRasterLayer
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo
#processing.alghelp("grass:r.walk")
path= 'd:/Works/_EvacuationSimulation/_raster/walk/'
filename1 = 'elevation.tif'
filename2 = 'friction.tif'
filename3 = 'destination.shp'
filename4 = 'walked.tif'

elevation = QgsRasterLayer(path + filename1, 'elevation')
friction = QgsRasterLayer(path + filename2, 'friction')
destination = QgsVectorLayer(path + filename3, 'destination',"ogr")

extent = elevation.extent()
xmin = extent.xMinimum()
xmax = extent.xMaximum()
ymin = extent.yMinimum()
ymax = extent.yMaximum()

min_area = 0.000100
#pixelsize = 0.000000
pixelsize = 0.100000

#processing.runalg('grass:r.walk', elevation, friction, destination, "0", "100", "", "0.72,6.0,1.9998,-1.9998", "1.0", "-0.2125",True,True, True, "%f,%f,%f,%f"% (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax), pixelsize, "-1", min_area, path + filename4)
processing.runalg('grass:r.walk', elevation, friction, destination, "0", "100", "", "0.72,6.0,1.9998,-1.9998", "1.0", "-0.2125",True,True, False, "%f,%f,%f,%f"% (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax), pixelsize, "-1", min_area, path + filename4)
```

After an execution without getting a result raster, the console log shows problematic rows:

```
    C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\bin>r.external -r input="d:\Works\_EvacuationSimulation\_raster\walk\unit-elevation.tif" band=1 output=tmp1482592256518 --overwrite -o 

    ERROR: r.external: Sorry, <r> is not a valid flag

    C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\bin>r.external -r input="d:\Works\_EvacuationSimulation\_raster\walk\friction-cost.tif" band=1 output=tmp1482592256519 --overwrite -o 

    ERROR: r.external: Sorry, <r> is not a valid flag


    C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\bin>r.walk  elevation="tmp1482592256518" friction="tmp1482592256519" start_points="tmp14825922565110" max_cost="0" percent_memory="100" walk_coeff="0.72,6.0,1.9998,-1.9998" lambda="1.0" slope_factor="-0.2125" -k -n output=outpute943ea890dd94b879185c7266a98f4c3 --overwrite 
    GRASS_INFO_ERROR(4668,5): Raster map <tmp1482592256518> not found

    GRASS_INFO_ERROR(5548,1): Raster map <outpute943ea890dd94b879185c7266a98f4c3> not found
```

Probably the problem comes from the built-in r.external function of the r.walk script, which uses a no longer exist '-r' flag.

Can you help to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved by changing the GRASS folder in Processing options to an older version:

C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.14\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3

(from C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.14\apps\grass\grass-7.0.5)

Comment: Yes, some years ago the -r flag was removed, see https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/wiki/Grass7/NewFeatures#Rastermodulechanges (refers to 7.0.0)

Answer (score 0):

Try writing this:

```
path= 'd:/Works/_Simulation/_raster/walk/'
```

instead of what you have provided or eliminating the `-` characters from your filenames.

Comment: I edited the code as you mentioned, but unfortunately happened the same :/ The vector layer have been read perfectly by the way, the problem can be still with the raster.

Comment: Do you have any cell in the raster layers with NULL values?

Comment: I uploaded the necessary layers here:
https://github.com/ewirth/evacuation/tree/master/data I haven't mentioned that the process work in grass gui, but I would like to automate it with these python code.
The elevation layer has only 0 and 1 values. The friction layer consist 0 and 'nan' cells as well.